# Unity not opening

Tags: unity

When I start my Unity it opens up the menu where I can select a project, but when I pick a project nothing happens. The process is still running in my windows but nothing shows up. Here is my log file:

```
LICENSE SYSTEM [20151210 20:3:23] No start/stop license dates set

LICENSE SYSTEM [20151210 20:3:23] Next license update check is after 2015-12-08T13:39:36

Built from '5.3/release/package-manager-disable' branch; Version is '5.3.0f4 (2524e04062b4) revision 2434272'; Using compiler version '160040219'
OS: 'Windows 10  (10.0.0) 64bit' Language: 'da' Physical Memory: 8110 MB
BatchMode: 0, IsHumanControllingUs: 1, StartBugReporterOnCrash: 1, Is64bit: 1, IsPro: 0
Initialize mono
Mono path[0] = 'G:/Program Files/Unity/Editor/Data/Managed'
Mono path[1] = 'G:/Program Files/Unity/Editor/Data/Mono/lib/mono/2.0'
Mono path[2] = 'G:/Program Files/Unity/Editor/Data/UnityScript'
Mono config path = 'G:/Program Files/Unity/Editor/Data/Mono/etc'
Using monoOptions --debugger-agent=transport=dt_socket,embedding=1,defer=y,address=0.0.0.0:56888
IsTimeToCheckForNewEditor: Update time 1449766327 current 1449774207
C:/Users/Halkjaer/Desktop/Roguelite
Loading GUID <-> Path mappings...0.000177 seconds
Loading Asset Database...0.016957 seconds
Audio: FMOD Profiler initialized on port 54900
AssetDatabase consistency checks...0.019347 seconds
Initialize engine version: 5.3.0f4 (2524e04062b4)
GfxDevice: creating device client; threaded=1
Direct3D:
    Version:  Direct3D 11.0 [level 11.0]
    Renderer: AMD Radeon HD 7800 Series (ID=0x6819)
    Vendor:   ATI
    VRAM:     2030 MB
Begin MonoManager ReloadAssembly
Platform assembly: G:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\Managed\UnityEngine.dll (this message is harmless)
Platform assembly: G:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\Managed\UnityEditor.dll (this message is harmless)
Platform assembly: G:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\Managed\Unity.Locator.dll (this message is harmless)
Refreshing native plugins compatible for Editor in 45.52 ms, found 0 plugins.
Platform assembly: G:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\Mono\lib\mono\2.0\I18N.dll (this message is harmless)
Platform assembly: G:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\Mono\lib\mono\2.0\I18N.West.dll (this message is harmless)
Platform assembly: G:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\Managed\Unity.DataContract.dll (this message is harmless)
Platform assembly: G:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\Mono\lib\mono\2.0\System.Core.dll (this message is harmless)
Platform assembly: G:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\Managed\Unity.IvyParser.dll (this message is harmless)
Platform assembly: G:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\Mono\lib\mono\2.0\System.dll (this message is harmless)
Platform assembly: G:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\Mono\lib\mono\2.0\System.Xml.dll (this message is harmless)
Platform assembly: G:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\Mono\lib\mono\2.0\System.Configuration.dll (this message is harmless)
Platform assembly: G:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\PackageManager\Unity\PackageManager\5.3.0\Unity.PackageManager.dll (this message is harmless)
Initializing Unity.PackageManager (PackageManager) v5.3.0 for Unity v5.3.0f4
Setting StandaloneWindows v5.3.0 for Unity v5.3.0f4 to G:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\WindowsStandaloneSupport
Setting Advertisements v5.3.0 for Unity v5.3.0f4 to G:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\UnityExtensions\Unity\Advertisements
  UnityEngine.Advertisements.dll (Extension) GUID: 739bbd9f364b4268874f9fd86ab3beef
  Editor/UnityEditor.Advertisements.dll (Extension) GUID: 97decbdab0634cdd991f8d23ddf0dead
Setting EditorTestsRunner v5.3.0 for Unity v5.3.0f4 to G:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\UnityExtensions\Unity\EditorTestsRunner
  Editor/nunit.framework.dll (Extension) GUID: 7cbab2be89b54486bbd23a6fe637d30e
  Editor/UnityEditor.EditorTestsRunner.dll (Extension) GUID: 3c0ad459c1534645b5d603b7cc258f97
Setting GUISystem v5.3.0 for Unity v5.3.0f4 to G:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\UnityExtensions\Unity\GUISystem
  UnityEngine.UI.dll (Extension) GUID: f5f67c52d1564df4a8936ccd202a3bd8
  Editor/UnityEditor.UI.dll (Extension) GUID: 80a3616ca19596e4da0f10f14d241e9f
Setting UNetHLAPI v5.3.0 for Unity v5.3.0f4 to G:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\UnityExtensions\Unity\Networking
  UnityEngine.Networking.dll (Extension) GUID: 870353891bb340e2b2a9c8707e7419ba
  Editor/UnityEditor.Networking.dll (Extension) GUID: 5f32cd94baa94578a686d4b9d6b660f7
Setting TreeEditor v5.3.0 for Unity v5.3.0f4 to G:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\UnityExtensions\Unity\TreeEditor
  Editor/UnityEditor.TreeEditor.dll (Extension) GUID: adebbd281f1a4ef3a30be7f21937e02f
Setting UnityAnalytics v5.3.0 for Unity v5.3.0f4 to G:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\UnityExtensions\Unity\UnityAnalytics
  UnityEngine.Analytics.dll (Extension) GUID: 852E56802EB941638ACBB491814497B0
Setting UnityPurchasing v5.3.0 for Unity v5.3.0f4 to G:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\UnityExtensions\Unity\UnityPurchasing
  UnityEngine.Purchasing.dll (Extension) GUID: 8E0CD8ED44D4412CBE0642067ABC9E44
Registering custom dll's ...
Register platform support module: G:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\WindowsStandaloneSupport/UnityEditor.WindowsStandalone.Extensions.dll
Registered in 0.049048 seconds.
Non platform assembly: C:\Users\Halkjaer\Desktop\Roguelite\Library\ScriptAssemblies\Assembly-CSharp-firstpass.dll (this message is harmless)
Loading C:\Users\Halkjaer\Desktop\Roguelite\Library\ScriptAssemblies\Assembly-CSharp-firstpass.dll into Unity Child Domain
Non platform assembly: C:\Users\Halkjaer\Desktop\Roguelite\Library\ScriptAssemblies\Assembly-CSharp.dll (this message is harmless)
Loading C:\Users\Halkjaer\Desktop\Roguelite\Library\ScriptAssemblies\Assembly-CSharp.dll into Unity Child Domain
Non platform assembly: C:\Users\Halkjaer\Desktop\Roguelite\Library\ScriptAssemblies\Assembly-CSharp-Editor.dll (this message is harmless)
Loading C:\Users\Halkjaer\Desktop\Roguelite\Library\ScriptAssemblies\Assembly-CSharp-Editor.dll into Unity Child Domain
Platform assembly: G:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\PackageManager\Unity\PackageManager\5.3.0\Unity.PackageManager.dll (this message is harmless)
Loading G:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\PackageManager\Unity\PackageManager\5.3.0\Unity.PackageManager.dll into Unity Child Domain
Non platform assembly: G:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\UnityExtensions\Unity\Advertisements\Editor\UnityEditor.Advertisements.dll (this message is harmless)
Loading G:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\UnityExtensions\Unity\Advertisements\Editor\UnityEditor.Advertisements.dll into Unity Child Domain
Non platform assembly: G:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\UnityExtensions\Unity\EditorTestsRunner\Editor\nunit.framework.dll (this message is harmless)
Loading G:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\UnityExtensions\Unity\EditorTestsRunner\Editor\nunit.framework.dll into Unity Child Domain
Non platform assembly: G:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\UnityExtensions\Unity\EditorTestsRunner\Editor\UnityEditor.EditorTestsRunner.dll (this message is harmless)
Loading G:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\UnityExtensions\Unity\EditorTestsRunner\Editor\UnityEditor.EditorTestsRunner.dll into Unity Child Domain
Non platform assembly: G:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\UnityExtensions\Unity\GUISystem\UnityEngine.UI.dll (this message is harmless)
Loading G:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\UnityExtensions\Unity\GUISystem\UnityEngine.UI.dll into Unity Child Domain
Non platform assembly: G:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\UnityExtensions\Unity\GUISystem\Editor\UnityEditor.UI.dll (this message is harmless)
Loading G:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\UnityExtensions\Unity\GUISystem\Editor\UnityEditor.UI.dll into Unity Child Domain
Non platform assembly: G:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\UnityExtensions\Unity\Networking\UnityEngine.Networking.dll (this message is harmless)
Loading G:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\UnityExtensions\Unity\Networking\UnityEngine.Networking.dll into Unity Child Domain
Non platform assembly: G:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\UnityExtensions\Unity\Networking\Editor\UnityEditor.Networking.dll (this message is harmless)
Loading G:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\UnityExtensions\Unity\Networking\Editor\UnityEditor.Networking.dll into Unity Child Domain
Non platform assembly: G:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\UnityExtensions\Unity\TreeEditor\Editor\UnityEditor.TreeEditor.dll (this message is harmless)
Loading G:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\UnityExtensions\Unity\TreeEditor\Editor\UnityEditor.TreeEditor.dll into Unity Child Domain
Non platform assembly: C:\Users\Halkjaer\Desktop\Roguelite\Assets\AstarPathfindingProject\Plugins\DotNetZip\Pathfinding.Ionic.Zip.Reduced.dll (this message is harmless)
Loading C:\Users\Halkjaer\Desktop\Roguelite\Assets\AstarPathfindingProject\Plugins\DotNetZip\Pathfinding.Ionic.Zip.Reduced.dll into Unity Child Domain
Non platform assembly: C:\Users\Halkjaer\Desktop\Roguelite\Assets\AstarPathfindingProject\Plugins\JsonFx\Pathfinding.JsonFx.dll (this message is harmless)
Loading C:\Users\Halkjaer\Desktop\Roguelite\Assets\AstarPathfindingProject\Plugins\JsonFx\Pathfinding.JsonFx.dll into Unity Child Domain
Non platform assembly: C:\Users\Halkjaer\Desktop\Roguelite\Assets\JMO Assets\Editor\JMOAssets.dll (this message is harmless)
Loading C:\Users\Halkjaer\Desktop\Roguelite\Assets\JMO Assets\Editor\JMOAssets.dll into Unity Child Domain
Platform assembly: G:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\Managed\UnityEditor.Graphs.dll (this message is harmless)
Loading G:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\Managed\UnityEditor.Graphs.dll into Unity Child Domain
Platform assembly: G:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\WindowsStandaloneSupport\UnityEditor.WindowsStandalone.Extensions.dll (this message is harmless)
Loading G:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\WindowsStandaloneSupport\UnityEditor.WindowsStandalone.Extensions.dll into Unity Child Domain
Platform assembly: G:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\Managed\nunit.core.interfaces.dll (this message is harmless)
Refreshing native plugins compatible for Editor in 0.22 ms, found 0 plugins.
Preloading 0 native plugins for Editor in 0.00 ms.
Platform assembly: G:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\Managed\Mono.Cecil.dll (this message is harmless)
Platform assembly: G:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\Managed\Unity.SerializationLogic.dll (this message is harmless)
Platform assembly: G:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\Mono\lib\mono\2.0\UnityScript.dll (this message is harmless)
Platform assembly: G:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\Managed\ICSharpCode.NRefactory.dll (this message is harmless)
Platform assembly: G:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\Mono\lib\mono\2.0\System.Xml.Linq.dll (this message is harmless)
Platform assembly: G:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\Managed\nunit.core.dll (this message is harmless)
Mono: successfully reloaded assembly
- Completed reload, in  0.782 seconds
Registering platform support modules:
Platform assembly: G:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\Mono\lib\mono\2.0\Boo.Lang.Compiler.dll (this message is harmless)
Platform assembly: G:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\Mono\lib\mono\2.0\Boo.Lang.dll (this message is harmless)
Platform assembly: G:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\Mono\lib\mono\2.0\Boo.Lang.Parser.dll (this message is harmless)
Platform assembly: G:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\Mono\lib\mono\2.0\UnityScript.Lang.dll (this message is harmless)
Platform assembly: G:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\Mono\lib\mono\2.0\Mono.Security.dll (this message is harmless)
Registered platform support modules in: 0.0837364s.
Native extension for WindowsStandalone target not found
Downloading http://update.unity3d.com/5.3/ivy.xml to C:\Users\Halkjaer\AppData\Local\Temp\unity\646921af-e00d-4550-b62c-10e4ee349599\ivy.xml
Validating Project structure ... 0.018937 seconds.
Refresh: detecting if any assets need to be imported or removed ... Refresh: elapses 0.018223 seconds (Nothing changed)
Task failed: Verifier Task
```

I was on 5.2 originally when this started happening. I have since upgraded to 5.3 in hopes that it would fix the problem, but it did not. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds more like your project isn't opening, Unity is starting fine. Create a new project and import the code, assets and settings. Something happened to your project file that corrupted it in some way.

Comment: It also happened on a new project I created. However, the issue seems to have resolved itself with no input from me - I can now open the old project again just fine. Thanks for the suggestion anyways!